# could not find SOA composite in JDeveloper 12c and also SOA extension for 12c

Tags: soa, oracle12c, jdeveloper

Installed JDEVLOPER 12c, but could not find SOA composite.

1) Tried HELP -> check for updates -> Check 'Spring & Oracle Weblogic SCA'-> restart did not help much.

2) Downloaded SOA Composite 11.1.1.9.0.99.99 Editor from below url for JDEVLOPER 12c, as I could not find 12c extension thinking 11 ext will work for 12c http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/156082.xml#oracle.sca.modeler

manually tried adding extension to 12c did not work

How can I open a new SOA application in JDEVLOPER Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.3.0

Answer (score 3):

In 12c you need to get the specific JDeveloper that is packaged in the SOA installation. SOA is no longer an extension.
Get it here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/downloads/index.html